# GORM comma separated values field

Tags: go, go-gorm

First of all I know this is bad practise and I can do the split on the client side anyway but I was wondering how it would be implemented on the backend.

I have this struct

```
type Article struct{
    ArticleId   int    `gorm:"column:article_id;primaryKey" json:"article_id"`
    Title       string `gorm:"column:title" json:"title"`
    Content     string `gorm:"column:content" json:"content"`
    Tags        string `gorm:"column:tags" json:"tags"`
}
```

And for tags I use comma separated values e.g. `tech,woman,mit`

I can implement a simple function to split the string manually

```
func splitTags(values string) []string {
    array := strings.Split(values, ",")
    return array
}
```

But how can I implement it as a custom type in my struct for it to split the Tags automatically and preferably also join the []string values when I set the Tags value?

P.S. The above struct is just an example.

Comment: Implement the [driver.Valuer](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Valuer) interface for writing to the database, and the [sql.Scanner](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner) interface for reading from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments and this [link](https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html#Implements-Customized-Data-Type), one option would be to create a custom `Tags` type.

```
type Tags []string

//Implement Scanner interface
func (t *Tags) Scan(value interface{}) error {
  val, ok := value.([]byte)
  if !ok {
    return errors.New(fmt.Sprint("wrong type", value))
  }
    
  *t = Tags(strings.Split(string(val), ","))
    
  return nil
}

//Implement Valuer interface
func (t Tags) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
  //this check is here if you don't want to save an empty string
  if len(t) == 0 {
    return nil, nil
  }

  return []byte(strings.Join(t, ",")), nil
}
```

Comment: Using `Tags        Tags `gorm:"column:tags" json:"tags"`` gives error about being the wrong type
Declaring `func (Tags) GormDataType() string {
 return "tag"
}` and using
`Tags        []string `gorm:"column:tags;type:tag" json:"tags"`` gives error about converting uint8 to string
and finally using `Tags        []uint8 `gorm:"column:tags;type:tag" json:"tags"`` gives no erros but produces hashes of the tag values which is logical due to the data type

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe it just needs to change inside the `Scan` and `Value` methods. Like `val, ok := value.([]byte)`, `*t = Tags(strings.Split(string(val), ","))` and `return []byte(strings.Join(t, ",")), nil`, leaving `type Tags []string` as it is.